# How can I output several numbers per line in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I am new in programming,so please don't laugh from my stupid question.

I wrote program which ask user for input a number than program should output all the numbers from 0 to that entered number(doesn't matter if it is positive or negative).
I have tried 3 different versions

Here is my code:

```
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int num = PutiL.validNum(min, max, "number");
//this my utility methode which check if number is in range and if it is not a double or letter
int i = 0, z;
int y = 0;

//3rd version
while (i <= num) {
    for (z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//2nd version
if (num > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i <= num; y++) {
        for (z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
           System.out.print(i + ",");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i > num; y--) {
        for (z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
           System.out.print(i + ",");
            i--;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

//1st version`enter code here`
if (num > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
       System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i >= num; i--) {
        System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Problem is that code doesn't stop straight after number typed in by user. Will someone give me a hint what is wrong as I don't have any more ideas.

And here is the PutiL methode

```
public static int validNum(int min, int max, String words) {
    int num;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter " + words);
        while (!kb.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Please re-enter ");
            kb.nextLine();
        }
        num = kb.nextInt();

        if (num < min || num > max) {
            System.out.println("Not in range - re-enter\tproper range is "
                    + min + " - " + max);
        }

    } while (num < min || num > max);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder, append all the stuff into one String, then output that as one line.

Comment: What is PutiL? and what's wrong with your first version? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: PutiL is my utility file where I have for example method to check if inserted number isn't a double or letter and if it is in set range,

Comment: ok @Szarley Dwarf, you can see my answer.. change `y` to `i` will make your loops stop. ^^.. happy coding

Comment: what does "number" mean in this context? where is the variable you want to assign to num? Which value does num have? Maybe you just post your PutiL.validNum(min, max, "number") method

Comment: @ Ahmad Azwar Anas -  I try that but then it skips every fort number and output is like this
15
0,1,2,3,
5,6,7,8,
10,11,12,13,
15,16,17,18,

Comment: can you show me, what kind of output would you like for?? ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
//2nd version
if (num > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= num; y++)  <== THIS MAKE INFINITE too, OKAY.. ^^, change i to stop
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        {
           System.out.print(i + ",");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} else
{
    for (i = 0; i > num; y--) <== THIS MAKE INFINITE LOOPS, OKAY.. ^^, it must i to stop
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        {
           System.out.print(i + ",");
            i--;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

don't forget to accepted the answer if it goes right.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

"program should output all the numbers from 0 to that entered number"
and
"I want them print for example 4 in a one line and than skip to another line"

```
if(num >=0) {

  for (z = 0; z <= num; z++)
  {
    System.out.print(z + " ");
    if(z > 0 && z%4==0)
      System.out.println();
  }

}
else {
  // similar loop for negatives
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: yes but I want them print for example 4 in a one line and than skip to another line

Comment: @SzarleyDwarf ok, I updated it.  The percent sign is the "modulus operator" check it out:  http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (number >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i >= number; i--) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Or a bit more concise and with duplicating the println statement...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int increment = number >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
    for (int i = 0; i != number + increment; i += increment) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the user a dialog and the value the user enters will count to zero.

First import:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
```

Then:

```
int user_choice = Integer.parseInt(
showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number."));

if(user_choice > 0){
  for(int temp = 0; temp <= user_choice; temp++){
  System.out.println(temp);    
  }
}
else{
  for(int temp = 0; temp >= user_choice; temp--){
  System.out.println(temp);    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help I solve it my self was really easy here is code I useit and now its work perfectly

```
for(i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            y++;
            if(y % 4 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i >= num; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            y++;
            if(y % 4 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

But thank you all again for giving my ideas.